# Checkboxes and dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, lambda, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

I have columns O and S with checkboxes that I want to have populated dates in columns P and T. Currently using a formula but it's updating to today and I need the date to be the day the checkbox was checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in T2:

```
=LAMBDA(x; x)(IF(S2; TODAY(); ))
```

and drag down/up as you need. consequently, you could also use `NOW` instead of `TODAY` if you wish so